# Magento 2: get image id for view.xml

Tags: magento-2.1

I've read several threads how to change the product image width and height in **app/code/design/vendor/module/etc/view.xml:**

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
 <images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
         <width>500</width>
         <height>500</height>
    </image>
  </images>
</media>
</view>
```

I'm wondering where to find out the image id, e.g. `category_page_list`, `category_page_grid` or `homepage_page_grid`.

I try to change the image width and height for the product detail view...

Comment: Which theme are you used currently luma or custom?

Comment: My own theme, based on Blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change product image size from **view.xml**

Copy **view.xml** file from

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml
```

add **view.xml** to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/etc/view.xml
```

You can find out all pages product images here. Change it as per you need.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: omg, so simple, thx a lot...